# Load local fonts for exe application css

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm having trouble in loading fonts in an application which is being developed. The fonts load late after the page is loaded.

1.How can I make the fonts load at the same time the page loads?

2.Would it be better if I declare fonts locally or through cdn?

CSS and HTML snippets below

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Bold';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/k3k702ZOKiLJc3WVjuplzBampu5_7CjHW5spxoeN3Vs.woff2) format('woff');
}

body {
  background: black;
}

label {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'OpenSans-Bold';
  color: #FFF;
}

.parent {
  width: 99%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.signin_page {
  width: 32%;
  background: black;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff">
<link rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v13/k3k702ZOKiLJc3WVjuplzBampu5_7CjHW5spxoeN3Vs.woff2">

<body>
  <div class="signin_page">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="email">
          <label for="signin_url">CMS</label>
        </td>
        <td class="sign_text"><input id="signin_url" type="text" required autofocus="autofocus" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="email">
          <label for="signin_id">Username</label>
        </td>
        <td class="sign_text"><input id="signin_id" type="text" required/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="email">
          <label for="signin_password">Password</label>
        </td>
        <td class="sign_text"><input id="signin_password" type="password" required/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="parent">
      <button id="sign-button" onclick="signin();">Sign In</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: declare locally, because it is possible that when the page loads, there is a little network issue that can prevent the files from loading in time

Comment: I have tried declaring it locally. But still gets a 1-second FOIT.

Comment: I see that you need OPEN SANS, If its not the normal one that  comes with css3 then you need to download the pack from google fonts and then reference. If not, you should have access to open sans just by doing font-family:'Open-sans' in your css file